# How to use Postfix on my PHP code?

Tags: php, sendmail, postfix-mta

I have a Php website and I have a function  that when you click on the button it will send an email notification.

The code is stored on our own server and we also used Zimbra as our email application.

I have configured the Postfix successfully and was able to send email using mail -s "Test subject" recipient@domain.com
The problem is on my Php code or configuration, when I click on the button which has the code in sending email notification it says Message Sent but I have not receive any email. My php code is :

```
  ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
  error_reporting( E_ALL );
  $from = "sample@sample.com.ph";
  $to = "sample@sample.com.ph";
  $subject = "PHP Mail Test script";
  $message = "This is a test to check the PHP Mail functionality";
  $headers = "From:" . $from;
  mail($to,$subject,$message, $headers);
  echo "Test email sent";
```

My php.ini is :

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail        -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
sendmail_path = /etc/postfix

Here is my main.cf in Postfix

```
myhostname = sample.sample.net 
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = sample.sample.net, localhost.com, localhost
#relayhost = sample.com
relayhost = 10.104.64.5
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 10.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
default_transport = smtp
relay_transport = smtp
inet_protocols = all
smtp_host_lookup=native
ignore_mx_lookup_error = yes
```

Did I miss some configuration to make my code work ?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: check the spam folder in your email.

Comment: Yes, I already checked the Spam folder, but there were no emails.